# Inter-app communication- Broadcast Intents vs Intent Services, which is better?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I need app A and B to communicate. Android provides several options such as broadcast intents, Intent services, AIDL, Content Providers etc. I want to focus more on broadcasts and intent services. Is there a clear winner? I guess it depends on the use case. In this use case upon receipt of some event (read intent) from app A, app B has to fetch some content from the server.

**Broadcast Receivers**
Can’t be used for long-running operations (I believe they can only run for 10 seconds)
Ideal for one-to-many communication

**IntentService**
Ideal for long running background operations

From a performance standpoint, given that both are based on Intennts, I did not find any differemce. If App B is nor running, it took approx. under 60 ms to wake up app B (again it depends on device hardware etc.)

Any thoughts?

Comment: "Is there a clear winner?" -- they are not really equivalents IMHO, and they often are used together.

Comment: Why would you use a BR and IntentService together when in some cases all you need is just an IntentService? Imagine two scenarios: 1. Upon receipt of some action/trigger from App A, you want app B to fetch something from a remote server Scenario 2:  Upon receipt of some action/trigger from App A, you want app B, C and D to fetch something from a remote server. IMO, scenario 1 is better addressed with an Intent Service than a Broadcast receiver (one-to-one communication). And, for scenario 2 which really requires a one-to-many communication, a BR is more appropriate. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Why would you use a BR and IntentService together when in some cases all you need is just an IntentService?" -- in your particular case, you might not. In many cases, there is an intermediary (e.g., a `PendingIntent` to be triggered by `AlarmManager`) which influences the decision (e.g., have to use a broadcast `PendingIntent` with `_WAKEUP` alarms). In many other cases, you do not control one of the ends (e.g., a system-sent broadcast `Intent`). I was speaking in general regarding the equivalence of the two techniques, not specifically for your scenario. My apologies.